# Double clicks on a element

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I make a script. That load a new image in a img tag. This is the script:

```
button.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    var img = $('#photo-gallery .teaser img');

    $('li', list).attr('data-flag', 'close');

    img.animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500, function() {
        $('img', teaser).attr("src", url);
    });

    img.animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500)

    $(this).closest('li').attr('data-flag', 'open');
});
```

But, i have a problem with this script. When you click fast on a button. If you are very quick succession click. Than the script doing al that click events. How can i fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a flag set it to `true as soon as the event execution starts` and set it to false when exectuion end. *If some other event is fired while alreadClicked flag is true then return from event without taking any action*.

```
alreadClicked = false;

button.click(function(e) {      

    if(alreadClicked)
         return; 

    alreadClicked = true;
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    var img = $('#photo-gallery .teaser img');

    $('li', list).attr('data-flag', 'close');

    img.animate({ opacity: 0 }, 500, function() {
        $('img', teaser).attr("src", url);
    });

    img.animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500)

    $(this).closest('li').attr('data-flag', 'open');
    alreadClicked = false;
});
```

Comment: `alreadClicked = false` should be inside one of the callbacks I'd guess, otherwise it's the same as nothing.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) permits to execute event only once

```
button.one("click", function(e) {
    /* code ... */
});
```